# If I choose to take Killbane's mask, am I completely locked out of the Apoca-fists?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

At the end of the **Murderbrawl XXXI** mission, you can either choose to take Killbane's mask, which allows you to acquire his mask to wear, or he will tell you the "secret of the Apoca-fists."

If I choose to take his mask, does this completely lock me out of the Apoca-fists on that save? Or will I get the option to purchase them later on?

Comment: Well, you can always equip the Apoca-fists in TF2!  If you had preordered the Steam version of Saints Row the Third, that is.

Comment: @Powerlord Considering I have the 360 version, that's a no go. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've been able to determine, and according to [this wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Apoca-Fist) entry, the only way to get them is either by letting Killbane keep his mask or by using a cheat code.

Comment: Well crap, I was afraid of that. Ah well. Setting people on fire when you taunt them is an acceptable substitute.

Comment: That's what it does? Awesome! I reload a previous save when I realised I could get the weapon instead, thinking the mask is just a simple clothing item...